# Open the_author_link() in a new window

Tags: author, links

I need an extra pair of eyes on this. I have customized a block of code in a function of a commercial theme, which is the following code:

```
    <div class="author-description">
        <h5><span class="fn"><?php the_author_link(); ?></span></h5>
        <p class="note"><?php the_author_meta( 'description', $id ); ?></p>
        <?php csco_post_author_social_accounts( $id ); ?>
    </div>
```

There's `the_author_link()` in it, which states either the name of the user, or the link to the website of the user, which can be filled in the admin users profile. The `the_author_link()` does not accept any parameters, according to the Codex.

I would like this function to open the link in a new window. Do I need to break the function down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to get the url by user's meta:

```
<?php
if ( get_the_author_meta('url') ) {
    // Author has website url
    $author_url = get_the_author_meta('url');
} else {
    // Author doesn't have website url, so get Author Posts Page
    $author_url = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID') );
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $author_url; ?>" target="_blank">Author's website</a>
```

Comment: I've added <?php the_author();?> to the <h5> to complete the code! 

        <h5><span class="fn"><a href="<?php echo $author_url; ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_author();?></a></span></h5>

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is one part where WordPress does not allow customization via filter or action, as you can see in the [source code for that function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/author-template.php#L191).

However, you can copy that code and make it your own

```
function wpse_get_author_link_target_blank() {
    if ( get_the_author_meta('url') ) {
        return sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author external" target="_blank">%3$s</a>',
        // added this part -------------------------------------------------^
            esc_url( get_the_author_meta('url') ),
            /* translators: %s: author's display name */
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Visit %s&#8217;s website' ), get_the_author() ) ),
            get_the_author()
        );
    } else {
        return get_the_author();
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
<h5><span class="fn"><?php echo wpse_get_author_link_target_blank(); ?></span></h5>
```

Comment: Rewriting the default function works also fine! Thnx for your help Kero.